# Webgrid checkbox selection lost after paging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, webgrid

I have a webgrid

```
@{       
var gdAdminGroup = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 20, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "tdUserAdminGroup");
}

@gdAdminGroup.GetHtml(
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "tdUserAdminGroup" },
    tableStyle: "gd",
    headerStyle: "gdhead",
    rowStyle: "gdrow",
    alternatingRowStyle: "gdalt",
        columns: gdAdminGroup.Columns(                
        gdAdminGroup.Column(columnName: "Description", header: "Admin Group"),
        gdAdminGroup.Column(header: "", format: @<text><input name="chkUserAdminGroup" type="checkbox" value="@item.AdminGroupID" @(item.HasAdminGroup == 0? null : "checked") /></text>)
       )
    )
```

If I check some checkboxs and goes to the second page, the selection on the first page will be lost. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Page selection is links why
- The page is refeshed via a GET command (< a href="...." not < input type="submit" ....)
- The link does not submit form in which you checkbox is in, why you can not read the state of the checkbox.

Either you should look for a JavaScript solution to amend the Checkbox data in the GET URL,
or find another Grid generator.

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&ProjectName=mvccontrib

Comment: This is wit much more details and a solution http://unboxedsolutions.com/sean/archive/2011/03/30/15977.aspx

Comment: And another enhancing the Webgrid solution, so you do not have to request all records in the database. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=618